# Connect to the Erlang node through DNS record

Tags: dns, network-programming, erlang, distributed

I have two nodes: `'test@rabbit001'` `'test@rabbit002'`.

There is a DNS record `test` which is a round robin between `rabbit001` and `rabbit002`.

First, I try to connect to the node using it's hostname and it's fine:

```
(test@rabbit002)54> net_kernel:connect('test@rabbit001').
true
```

test@rabbit002 logs: http:// pastebin.com/yELBpE82

test@rabbit001 logs: http:// pastebin.com/iF23UPgf

Then when I try to connect to the node using that DNS record:

```
(test@rabbit002)57> net_kernel:connect('test@test').
false
```

test@rabbit002 logs: http://pastebin.com/M6FbUTDH

test@rabbit001 logs: http://pastebin.com/rfH0HsEK

**Is it possible to make them communicate properly?**

The networking is not a problem, I've confirmed that actual net_kernel functions are being called on `'test@rabbit001'` when I try to do a `net_kernel:connect` from `'test@rabbit002'`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to use a round robin DNS record to balance Erlang inter-node communications. The node name is not only used to resolve the hostname, but the remote node must be using that exact same name. You'll have to implement some kind of load balancing in Erlang.